# Finding domain of $f(x)$

Tags: analysis, functions

Find the domain of $f(x)$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\cos(\sin x)}+\arcsin \left(\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right)$$

*My Approach:*

$\cos(\sin x) \geq 0 ; -1\leq \frac{1+x^2}{2x} \leq 1$

The first inequality holds for all $x$ and, for second one we have:

$(x+1)^2 \geq 0$ and, $(x-1)^2 \leq 0$ which is true only for $x=1$

*My Problem:*

The answer mentioned in the book is $x=1,-1$

I want to know how $-1$ is in the domain.

Comment: Repnace x by -1 and you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for the arc sine is
$$\left\lvert\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right\rvert\le 1\iff x\ne 0 \,\text{ and }\,1+x^2\le 2\lvert x\rvert\iff x\ne 0 \,\text{ and }\,(1-\lvert x\rvert)^2\le 0$$
which is satisfied if and only if $\;\lvert x\rvert=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$\forall x>0$
$$1+x^2\geq 2x $$
$$\implies \frac {1+x^2}{2x}\geq 1$$

the equality holds for $x=1$

and
$\forall x <0$
$$1+x^2\geq -2x $$
$$\implies \frac {1+x^2}{2x}\leq -1$$

the equality holds for $x=-1$

the domain is then $\{-1,1\} $.

Answer (score 0):

you have $$-1\le \frac{1+x^2}{2x}\le 1$$
in the case that $$x>0$$ we get
$$0\le (1+x)^2$$ which is true.
and $$(x-1)^2\le 0$$ which gives $$x=1$$
int the case that $$x<0$$ we get
$$-2x\geq 1+x^2\geq 2x$$
which gives $$0\le (x+1)^2$$ thus $$x=-1$$ and $$(x-1)^2\geq 0$$